# R Programming - How to create a histogram from a defined number of specific cells in a row?

Tags: dataframe, histogram

I am tying to create a histogram from a defined number of specific cells in a row.

Hello All,

I'm quite experienced with statistics but new to the R language. I am tying to create a histogram from a defined number of specific cells in a row.

I have created the following table to illustrate the format my data is in:

[Example data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6XR6.png)

I am trying to create a histogram which lists just the car values, from col 3 onwards.

I know I can enter the data like this :

```
> y=c(7500,6500,2400,10000,15000)
> hist(y)
```

which works,  but my actual data set has 500+ subjects so a command line approach such as this is not really feasible. So I have tried (for example)

```
> y=c(data.frame(3,3:7))
> hist(y)
```

but get -
`Error in hist.default(y) : 'x' must be numeric.`

In English - with my actual data - I suppose I am saying - "plot a histogram for data in row x, but only for the cells from column 3 to column 578".